# How do I force TextEdit to not add .txt extension (Sierra)

Tags: macos, textedit, file-extensions

I have TextEdit default to plain text files. I also have "Add .txt extension to plain text files" unchecked in the "Preferences" in the "Open and Save" section.

If I perform these steps:

1. Create new document
2. Write some text
3. Click on title bar to set the filename and save it
4. Type `foobar.md` in the "Name" box
5. Hit "Enter"

The result is that the file is actually named `foobar.md.txt`.

How can I get TextEdit to actually not add `.txt` to file names? And what is the point of that box in "Preferences" if it doesn't actually do anything?

Comment: What OS version are you using?

Comment: I'm on sierra 10.12.5

Comment: I use Textedit but I don't have that problem.  I just recently saved a file as .out and it worked fine.  Even with txt box checked, it gave me option of using .txt or .out   I'm using 10.12.6

Comment: @john did you click the title bar to set the name and save, or did you use File -> Save?

Comment: I used File -> save or save as.  (save as appears if you hold down the option key while clicking on file menu.)

Comment: I see this with .ini files but not .sh. Maybe it's files MacOS knows about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the name in the title bar to change or set the file name. Use the file menu option save, or hold the option key and select save as.  This lets you chose your extension name. I encountered a similar problem using title bar to name the file.

Comment: This works but negates the handy feature of duplicating a file.

Comment: What do you mean by "hold the option key and select save as". Where/how/when is that done?